# Make #include "foo/bar.h" actually get "foo/inc/bar.h"

Tags: c, include, include-path, code-organization

If I have project structured like this:

```
project/
  module-X/
    inc/
      x.h
    src/
      x.c
  module-Y/
    inc/
      y.h
    src/
      y.c
  module-Z/
    inc/
      z.h
    src/
      z.cpp
```

And I have `CFLAGS += -I$(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR)`.

Is there some way to make it so I can write `#include "module-X/x.h"` instead of `#include "module-X/inc/x.h"`? I want to have the `module-X` in the `#include` to get explicit namespacing, but the `inc/` part is just noise.

The solutions I have all have flaws:

- #### Move the headers into root `module-X/` dir

  - Mixes headers with other things that need to be there (e.g. makefiles), that may not be as public as the headers.
- #### Keep the sources in `module-X/inc/module-X/x.h`, add `module-X/inc` to include path

  - Would require every module to be added to `CFLAGS`, doesn't scale well.
- #### Restructure the project so headers are in `project/inc/module-*/`

  - A module is not self-contained anymore.

Is there another option I'm missing?

(code needs to be compilable with gcc, clang and msvc)

Comment: Why not reference all those files by their proper path, which is `foo/inc/bar.h` instead of creating confusion with `foo/bar.h` includes and **knowing** to expect `foo/inc/bar.h` ?

Comment: Why don't you `-I$(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR)/module-X/inc` and then write `#include "x.h"` ?

Comment: @LP: Personally, I prefer header files that are explicit about what they belong to. Actually, I would suggest the OP making "`project`" part of the include line as well. In code making use of many different third-party libraries, this helps a lot figuring out which header comes from where.

Comment: @DevSolar I agree, as far as I can avoid to write something like `"../../libProject1/src/include"` due to a big workspace with a lot of different projects.

Comment: @DevSolar If included from outside of "project", agreed. But for sibling modules, it doesn't seem that useful.

Comment: @Shark It may violate the principle of least astonishment, but if the behavior is consistent it isn't that big a deal. And it makes things easier to read and write - especially since it's not just "inc/", but may end up being a rather lengthy name.

Comment: Two reasons:
1) it makes it very frustrating/difficult to figure that out at 4am when you're debugging before the demo
2) without proper documentation, once you leave the project it becomes a very large deal.

Hiding 'things' never makes things easier IMO, but perhaps we're just different types of team-players.

Answer (score 4):

Would a `bash` solution be OK?

In directory `project`...

```
mkdir includes
for module in module-*
do
    ln -s "${module}/inc" "includes/${module}"
done
```

Then add `project/includes` to the include path.

Similar things can be done with CMake, DOS batch etc.

Comment: I think you can fit this in the `Makefile` itself :)

Comment: Very good idea. I generally hate links in the project (too many problems with different platforms), but these would be created on the fly, and wouldn't be stored in the repo, so it would work. Awesome.